# How to extend an HDMI port of raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, hdmi

I am using raspberry pi as part of a project. Raspberry pi will be placed inside my hardware.It has a closed container. Because of the placing of other components, I can't move the position of the raspberry Pi. The problem is,I want to connect my Screen to this hardware. Is there any kind of HDMI port extension cables so that I can extend the HDMI port to casing of the hardware. and is it a reliable solution when it comes to Raspberry pi-?

Comment: Please give us an idea of the length required? Would you want something solid or flexible? Is it the traditional Pi or the new 4 with Micro HDMI?

Comment: I really need a short cable. approximately 20cm. That is the distance between the raspi and the back side of the case. i want to attach some kind of hdmi adapter to the backside of the body so that user can plug in to it. I am using Raspi 3B+

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a very short HDMI cable and a female-female HDMI adapter.  These are both standard things you could easily find on Amazon.  Make sure both are rated for your application and you should be good to go.  If you need more specific advice, you'd have to be more specific about your hardware and your application.

Comment: Based on the comment you added to your question after I posted my answer, I went to Amazon and performed two searches:
1) hdmi 1ft
2) hdmi female-female
Looks to me like you can find what you want using only those.  The HDMI cable will be about 10cm longer than you need it to be, but there will be an abundance of options.  You could also search for something like hdmi 1ft male-female instead, then the extra length could remain outside of the case with no adapter necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To connect my RPi3B+ to an HDMI monitor, I purchased the following cable and it works great. I'm hoping to use this same cable for my incoming RPi4B along with an adapter I also got on amazon.com.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B014ROO71W/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014ROO71W)